# define equal xshift or yshift for all nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, landscape

I'm rather new to tikz and I'm drawing a flow chart based on a template. I'm currently defining xshift and yshift separately for every node:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} %call package for drawing
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta}

\tikzset{%
  >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
  % Specifications for style of nodes:
            base/.style = {rectangle, draw=black,
                           minimum width=2cm, minimum height=0.75cm,
                           text centered, %font=\sffamily
                       },
  mystyle/.style = {base, fill=orange!40},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm,
    every node/.style={fill=white, font=\sffamily}, align=center]

\node (mynode) [mystyle] {mynode};
\node (mynode2) [mystyle, right of=mynode, xshift=3cm, yshift=2cm] {mynode2};
\node (mynode3) [mystyle, right of=mynode2, xshift=3cm] {mynode3};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to specify that `xshift`  should always be a certain value that is defined in the preamble? Right now it would be `xshift = 3cm`, but maybe later on I'll change my mind and want to change it to 2cm everywhere, so it would be nice to have a convenient way to do so. In addition, I would still like to keep the option to define positioning for individual nodes (so maybe nearly all `xshift` options should be `3cm`, except for one where I would e.g. specify `4cm` manually).

Comment: `\newcommand{\myxs}{3cm}` and then use `xshift=\myxs`? Should work *almost* everywhere.

Comment: Anyway, you can just change `node distance` too, no?

Comment: oh thanks, both are easy solutions!

Comment: @Nereus have look at the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could edit the following code

```
  mystyle/.style = {base, fill=orange!40, xshift=3cm},
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} %call package for drawing
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta}

\tikzset{%
  >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
  % Specifications for style of nodes:
            base/.style = {rectangle, draw=black,
                           minimum width=2cm, minimum height=0.75cm,
                           text centered, %font=\sffamily
                       },
  mystyle/.style = {base, fill=orange!40, xshift=3cm},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm,
    every node/.style={fill=white, font=\sffamily}, align=center]

\node (mynode) [mystyle] {mynode};
\node (mynode2) [mystyle, right of=mynode,  yshift=2cm] {mynode2};
\node (mynode3) [mystyle, right of=mynode2,] {mynode3};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: might want to create a separate style though if OP already applies that style to nodes that are *not* to be shifted, e.g. `myshift/.style = {xshift=3cm}`